How do i set timezones with Symfony translation and the ICU message format?
I'm storing all my dates as UTC in the database. But I want to display them in the users timezone.
$mydate = new \DateTime('2024-08-07 12:00:00');

Displaying the dates in Twig with the date filter like {{ mydate|date('d.m.Y H:i:s', 'Europe/Berlin') }} works as expected and shows 07.08.2024 14:00:00
But when I use the translation feature in combination with the ICU message format I have no idea how to set the desired timezone for displaying the dates.
I'm using the ICU message format as documented in https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/formats/message_format.html#date-and-time. And the following is such an example message of my application.
my_message: the date and time is {mydate, date} {mydate, time, full}

<div>{{ my_message|trans({mydate: mydate}) }}</div>

<!-- my locale is DE -->
<div>07.08.2024 12:00:00 Koordinierte Weltzeit Uhr</div>

If I set date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin') the output of the translation is the same as before. But because I tell PHP that all my dates should have a default timezone of Europe/Berlin the twig filter displays display the same data also. Because it converts Europe/Berlin to Europe/Berlin and therefore displays 12:00:00 instead of 14:00:00.

{{ my_message|trans({mydate: mydate|date("d/m/Y H:i", "Europe/Berlin") }) }}

Thx @Rufinus for your suggestion. That is a possible solution I'm already aware of. But as mentioned in my post I'm using the ICU message format where the date formatting happens inside the translation string. I added a link to the Symfony docs in the original post.

With PHP's DateTime, the time zone is a property of the DateTime object itself.  Thus, you should set the time zone when creating your $mydate variable, before rendering it for display with the ICU message.  In other words, the time zone is not part of the display format, but part of the underlying data.
Since you said your data is in UTC, then you can convert from UTC to the desired time zone after loading your data.  There are some examples here of how to do that.
